# if assertion in z3py

Tags: python, validation, z3, z3py

i'm a new user for z3py. I need to write a program that check satisfaction of some rule like

```
IF room.temp < 18 THEN room.fireplace = on  
IF room.temp > 24 THEN room.fireplace = off  
IF room.CO > 180  THEN room.fireplace = off  
IF room.temp > 28 THEN house.hvac = off  
IF house.hvac == on THEN room.fireplace = off
```

also how to write this

```
bedroom.occupancy  ==  true  and  bedroom.env_brightness  <=  31.5 and  bedroom.light.switch = on
```

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need a Z3 If-then-else which can be defined using `If` in z3.

```
>>> x = Int('x')
>>> y = Int('y')
>>> max = If(x>y, x, y)
>>> max
If(x > y, x, y)
```

For defining multiple constraints you can use `And` and `Or`

```
>>> max = If(And(x>y, x!=0), x, y)
>>> max
If(And(x > y, x != 0), x, y)
>>> simplify(max)
If(And(Not(x <= y), Not(x == 0)), x, y)
```

Hope this helps.
[This](https://github.com/0vercl0k/z3-playground) is a great resource to start with z3py in general.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. but how can I use solver object to create constraints and check if those constraints are satisfy under some policies "conditions"

Comment: This works perfectly in Solver too. Have a look at https://github.com/ByteBandits/writeups/blob/master/csaw-finals-2016/reverse/rev250/sudhackar/rev250.py. I'm on phone and thats all I could find.